# how to parse datetime to a certain format?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, datetime

How to I format datetime from sql to certain format user defined in C#? For example, the datetime in sql is like 2011-02-06 12:00:21, the user defined format is mmddyyyy, I am expecting output is 02062011 (note that not 262011). How do I do the conversion in C#?

Comment: Do you want a `string` output?  Or a `DateTime` without the time part?

Comment: select replace(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101) ,'/','')                  you can do this in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
((DateTime)reader["DateColumn"]).ToString("MMddyyyy");
```

Assuming `reader["DateColumn"]` returns a `DateTime` object

Comment: I think you mean `ToString`. There's no `ToDate` method on `DateTime`

Comment: @vlad Thank you! Yes, that's what I meant!

Comment: I got an error saying there is no overload ToString that takes 1 parameter. I tried like row["datecolumn"].ToString("MMddyyyy"). The Type of row is DataRow.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is the correct format in [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx). In your case, that's `MMddyyyy`. For example:

```
var myDate = new DateTime(2011,2,6,12,0,21);
Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific. Consuming you have DateTime object. If you want to show it you can use `ToString` overload method:

```
new DateTime(2011, 2, 6).ToString("MMddyyyy");
```

Comment: `mm` is for minutes. He wants months `MM`